# How do I get month and year from date type in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get data from a specific month and year from a start date and end date with date datatypes. lets say the start date is march 7 2017 and the end date is dec 15 2035

```
Declare @monthid as varchar(8)
set @monthid = 'jan 2020'

Convert(char(4), startdate,100) + convert(char(4), startdate,120) <= @monthid
Convert(char(4), enddate,100) + convert(char(4), enddate,120) >= @monthid
```

Comment: By using [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), however you mention using the date datatype but in your example you have nothing but strings unless startdate and enddate are dates in your actual table.

Comment: Is that what you *really* want, or do you actually want to compare with a *specific* month in a year? In the latter case something like `DATEFROMPARTS` or converting `jan 2020` to `20200101` should be what you want, not to manipulate the base date/time columns.

Comment: @SeanLange the actual table has start and end dates as date.  the example is just me trying to get jan 2022 data

Comment: Then you should instead of a varchar(8) create a date datatyped variable. That way you can keep your predicates sargable.

Comment: @SeanLange the monthid is coming from another table which is a varchar

Comment: @OEGM2002 Why? You only create more problems and work storing month/year as a string that includes a language dependency.

Comment: Then your real question is how to convert `jan 2020` to a `DATE`. You always want to go from text to date if your indexed columns are dates, not the other way around. As it so happens the default style already accommodates exactly this conversion (`CONVERT(DATE, 'jan 2020')`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of string manipulation and then a lot of effort to manipulate the existing data you should use the proper datatype in your variable. This has two benefits. The first being that your code would be a lot simpler. The second being that your code is sargable so you can utilize any indexes you may have on those date columns. Since your example was only a snippet I can only provide a snipper in return. But something like this should be a lot easier and faster.

```
declare @DateCompare datetime = '20200101'

startdate <= @DateCompare
enddate >= @DateCompare
```